# Group of isometries generated by an isometry.

Tags: group-theory, geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, isometry

The following question is stated on an exercise sheet of Riemannian Geometry.

We look at the pseudo Riemannian metric, defined on $M = \mathbb{R}^2 \ 0 $ by

\begin{align*}
< \partial_x, \partial_x > &= < \partial_y, \partial_y> = 0 \\
< \partial_x, \partial_y > &= \frac{2}{x^2 + y^2}
\end{align*}

Show that the map $F(x,y) = 2(x,y)$ is an isometry and that the group of isometries $\Gamma$ generated by $F$ acts in a proper and discontinuous way on $M$. Hence $\frac{M}{\Gamma}$, which can be identified with the annulus between radius 1 and 2 (with both curves identified), is a torus and therefore compact.

I do not know

- what the group of isometries generated by a certain isometry is
- How to take the quotient group of a manifold and an isometry group
- what to interprete as a proper and discontinuous action.

I do have knowledge of group theory, quotient groups and isometries, but their use in this particular context confuses me and the course material nor the internet is helping me any further.

Could someone help me out with those definitions/interpretations? Any help is duly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: This is a big question, perhaps too broad. You might be missing a lot of mathematical knowledge, in which case to answer your question would require a textbook. From group theory, do you know the definition of the subgroup generated by a subset? From topology, do you know anything about group actions on topological spaces? Do you know any covering space theory, which is a part of topology? If you don't know any of these things, I would suggest narrowing your question down, starting perhaps with just the question in your first bullet point.

Comment: If you *do* know some of these things, it would be good to say so **explicity** by editing your question, otherwise you are inviting your potential answerers to write a futile textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group of isometries generated by $F$ is simply the set of powers of $F$ (i.e. $\{1, F, F^2, F^3, \dots\}$) and their inverses. Since $F$ is just rescaling by $2$, the group is just all rescalings by powers of $2$.

The quotient manifold $M \, / \, \Gamma$ is the set of equivalence classes of points in $M$ under the equivalence relation of being in the same orbit of $\Gamma$. By the description above, this means that $(x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2)$ if there is some integer $n$ so that $(x_2,y_2) = 2^n (x_1,y_1)$. So in the quotient, the points $(x,y)$, $(2x,2y)$, $(4x,4y)$, $(8x,8y)$, etc... all represent the same point. It can be identified by the annulus because any point can be multiplied by some $2^n$ to bring it to a point with a radius between 1 and 2. In other words, any equivalence class has a representative in this annulus.

The definition of properly discontinuous action can be found in a topology textbook. For example, see the wikipedia page: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)#Types_of_actions).

Comment: Thank you! That definitely clarifies it enough to start working on it.